# jQuery removeClass and addClass not working with specific CSS selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a simple website and want to add a class to inputs when they match.

I was previously trying to add the class (and remove the error class) using this:

```
var pass1Obj = $('#SignUpPassword');
var pass2Obj = $('#SignUpPasswordRep');
$(pass1Obj, pass2Obj).removeClass('failInput');
$(pass1Obj, pass2Obj).addClass('successInput');
```

but that was not working. It was retrieving both of the objects but only adding and removing the class on the first object (pass1Obj).

This works though.

```
var pass1Obj = $('#SignUpPassword');
var pass2Obj = $('#SignUpPasswordRep');
$(pass2Obj).removeClass('failInput');
$(pass2Obj).addClass('successInput');
$(pass1Obj).removeClass('failInput');
$(pass1Obj).addClass('successInput');
```

I am using jquery version 3.4.1 from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js

Why does selecting and changing the objects individually work but selecting multiple not?

Comment: Should be `pass2Obj.removeClass('...');`

Comment: you can use .add():  `pass1Obj.add(pass2Obj).removeClass('...');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why does selecting and changing the objects individually work but selecting multiple not?*

As per the jQuery object `$(pass1Obj, pass2Obj)`, You are specifying the [context](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) which internally converts to

```
$(pass2Obj).find(pass1Obj)
```

and since `pass1Obj` is not a child of `pass2Obj` the above code didn't work.

---

You could have used [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/#add-selector) to create a new jQuery then the desired operation can be performed on it.

```
pass1Obj.add(pass2Obj).toggleClass('failInput successInput');
```

Here is an example.

```js
var p1 = $("#para1"),
  p2 = $("#para2");

p1.add(p2).toggleClass("red green");
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="para1" class="red">Para1</p>
<p id="para2" class="red">Para2</p>
```